# An urn contains $N$ balls out of which $R$ are red and $B$ are blue. We picked randomly $10$ balls. Find the the expecting average of red balls.

Tags: probability, expectation

Can't figure this out, please help

> An urn contains $N$ balls out of which $R$ are red and $B$ are blue. 
>   After picking randomly $10$ balls, find the formula for the expecting average of red balls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Distribute the 10 balls you picked randomly among ten numbered bins, one ball in each. Then compute the expected number of red balls in bin 1, *plus* the expected number or red balls in bin 2, et cetera, *plus* the expected number of red balls in bin 10.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Recall that if $I$ is an indicator random variable, then
$$E[I] = P(I = 1).$$
Let $I_j$ for $j =1,\dotsc, 10$ denote the event that the $j$th ball drawn is red.
Then $$N = I_1+\dotsb+I_{10}$$ denotes the number of reds.